# Disable flash button and div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

In my application, I've created 3 boxes. In the first button, I'm using a flash button, in my second button, I'm using a `<div>` element, and in my third button, I'm also using a `<div>` element. If I click the flash button that shows images from the disk to upload.

If I click the second box, it means that some operation should be performed, and if I click the third box, some other operation should be performed.

What I need to happen is if I click the first button, I want to disable the second and third buttons, if I click on the second button, I want to disable the first and third buttons, and if I click the third button, I want to disable the first and second buttons.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class (`addCallback` and `call` methods)